# From where does snooze pop up comes in ScheduledNotification?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Just wondering from where does the snooze pop up gets triggered when using ScheduledNotification, I mean I want to give it some effects so as to get a fancy pop up rather than just normal pop-up window. tried to check everything everywhere but could not find how to edit or override the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScheduledNotification`s are handled by the OS, so cannot be made any more "fancy" -- if you wanted to do something different, you would need to implement that yourself, along with all the frameworks to do so.